# Is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter thread safe?

Tags: java, json, spring, jms

Can you please tell is `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter` thread safe class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is. According to [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MappingJackson2MessageConverter.html) it uses jackson for message conversion. If you inspect the code for MappingJackson2MessageConverter, the are only two local variables: objectMapper and boolean to indicate pretty print. According to [Jackson FAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ) objectMapper is thread safe.